# Analyse measurement data with machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, fitting, curve-fitting, measurement

I am frequently receiving measurement data of a particular shape. The data come from a measurement and look roughly like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreading_resistance_profiling#/media/File:Deep_and_Shallow_SR_profiles_portrait.jpg

The profile doesn't really follow a specific function. I would be able to fit some plateaus, but the area between the plateaus is hard to describe by a function.

My question is, if machine learning is suitable for monitoring these profiles. I have a couple of data sets (between 10 and 100, depending on the specific profile), which are quite similar, but not identical. The plateau level can differ within a certain range and the change from one to another can be a different positions.

But generally, they are quite comparable. I want to use machine learning now, to identify, if some new measurement doesn't fit. E.g., the plateau level is too high, or if there is an additional peak, which shouldn't be in the profile.

How can I approach this problem? Normally I would use python for programming, additionally, I have access to the software "statistica", which already offers plenty of machine learning tools, however, I have no experience with machine learning and don't know how to get started.

I hope you can give me a hint, thanks a lot!

Comment: This sounds like anomaly detection. Without getting into methods to do so (I hardly have expertise), does that sound like a way to describe what you want to do?

Comment: @Dave, yes, that's heading into the right direction. I want to detect, if one of the profiles differs in any feature from the "baseline"/reference